# How to quickly calculate all the line segments when their coordinate in the Hough transform is given

Tags: image-processing, hough-transform

Hough transform is a very powerful tool to find dominant straight lines in a black-and-white image. A very common practice of analyzing Hough transform result is to find some local maximum points in the Hough transform image, and then try to analyze the straight line segments in the image domain that correspond to the local maximum point. Then the question arises: how can we quickly calculate all the line segments when their coordinate in the Hough transform is given? For the time being, I have a awkward way to solve this problem:

- first calculate the straight line function that correspond to the
  Hough transform point.
- after that, find all the line segments    that have intersections
  with the calculated straight line. In the    meantime, I make sure
  that all the pixels in the line segments are    near to the
  calculated straight line by setting a some threshold.

Any ideas will be appreciated.